# Invalid mode: wb when trying to upload file using Django and AJAX

Tags: python, django, macos

So I'm trying to use an [ajax file upload form](http://kuhlit.blogspot.com/2011/04/ajax-file-uploads-and-csrf-in-django-13.html) with Django and running into an issue with FileIO. Specifically,

```
with BufferedWriter( FileIO( filename, "wb" ) ) as dest:
```

results in

> ValueError: invalid mode: wb

I'm running Python 2.6/Django 1.3 locally on OSX 10.6.7. I tried chmod +X to the directory I'm targeting with the filename. Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/io.html#raw-file-i-o

> FileIO represents a file containing bytes data. It implements the RawIOBase interface (and therefore the IOBase interface, too).
>
> The mode can be 'r', 'w' or 'a' for reading (default), writing, or appending. The file will be created if it doesn’t exist when opened for writing or appending; it will be truncated when opened for writing. Add a '+' to the mode to allow simultaneous reading and writing.

The "mode" is what you're trying to set is where you use "rb," which in the documentation isn't a valid mode. Either way, the fact that it's reading in raw data from a file seems to indicate that FileIO is set in binary mode by default--so the "b" seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: 'b' was totally unnecessary. For some reason I was dead set on having 'b' set since it was obviously binary! Thanks for helping me get past that.